# Incorrect display of JLabels in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, label, jpanel

EDIT : 
Ok, I found out why.

My getX and getY were overriding the Component ones. So my output was like 1 pixel wise... Should have thought of that earlier.

Thanks to those who tried to help me !

Original Question :

I have this Board class which inherits from JPanel which is supposed to display a board (seriously) composed of Squares which are black or white labels. I'm using a GridLayout but when I launch the application (after putting my JPanel in some dummy JFrame) the JLabels appear to be stacked on top of each other in the left hand corner which is not what I want. However the mouse listener seems to behave correctly since I get the good coordinates and the labels' color toggle between black and white.

Here is the code :

```
public class Board extends JPanel {
private int dimx,dimy;
private Square[][] squares;

public Board(int x, int y){
    super();
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(x,y));

    dimx = x;
    dimy = y;
    squares = new Square[dimx][dimy];
    for(int i=0; i<dimx; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<dimy; j++){
            Square sq = new Square(i,j);
            squares[i][j] = sq;
            this.add(sq);
            sq.addMouseListener(new SquareListener(i,j,this));
        }
    }
}

public Square[][] getSquares() {
    return squares;
}
}

public class Square extends JLabel {

private boolean black;
private int x,y;
private char c;

public Square(int x, int y){
    super();
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    setBorder(blackline);
    setOpaque(true);
    setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    this.x = x;
    this.y =y;

    c = ' ';
}

public void toggle(){
    black = !black;
}

public boolean isBlack(){
    return black;
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}

public char getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(char c) {
    this.c = c;
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if(isBlack()){
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else{
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
}


public class SquareListener implements MouseListener{

private int x,y;
private Board board;

public SquareListener(int x, int y, Board b){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.board = b;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    board.getSquares()[x][y].toggle();
    board.repaint();
    System.out.println("Clicked on "+x+","+y);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Consider posting your 'solution' as an answer and accept that one. This clearly shows in the overview that this question is answered. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) states it's OK to answer your own question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't change the background color inside the `paintComponent()` method. You shouldn't even have a `paintComponent()` method. And you also shouldn't have to call `repaint()`. Your `toggle()` method should be the one that changes the background:

```
public void toggle(){
    black = !black;
    setBackGround(black ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
}
```

Finally, the `getX()` and `getY()` methods override methods from JComponent. Choose another name for these methods.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, removed the paint component and stuff related. Still, I get this output :

http://hfr-rehost.net/http://self/pic/99790c5fde93314725a89752791ee547c168cdd1.png

Rather than a nice grid. Moreover I tested with regular Jlabels and it works, must be a problem in my Square definition...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out why.

My getX and getY were overriding the Component ones. So my output was like 1 pixel wise instead of being 1 square wise... Should have thought of that earlier.

Thanks to those who tried to help me !